# Python or pandas split columns by comma and append into rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset looks like this:
[image: 1]

I want to split the second column and then append the values like this using python or pandas:

[image: 2]

How could I change it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pandas DataFrame has `explode` method that does exactly what you want. [See explode() documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html). It works with list-like object, so if the column you want to explode is of type string, then you need to split it into list. [See str.split() documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html?highlight=str%20split#pandas.Series.str.split). Additionally you can remove any white spaces with Pandas [map function](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html?highlight=map#pandas.Series.map).

Full code example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "x": [1,2,3,4],
    "y": ["a, b, c, d", "e, f, g", "h, i", "j, k, l, m, n"]
})

# Convert string with commas into list of string and strip spaces
df['y'] = df['y'].str.split(',').map(lambda elements: [e.strip() for e in elements])

# Explode lists in the column 'y' into separate values
df.explode('y')
```

Output:

```
   x  y
0  1  a
0  1  b
0  1  c
0  1  d
1  2  e
1  2  f
1  2  g
2  3  h
2  3  i
3  4  j
3  4  k
3  4  l
3  4  m
3  4  n
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 6):

You can make use of `explode`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'B': ['ab,s', 'a,s,d,f', 'rk,lw', 'get,me']})

# Split by each comma
df.B = df.B.str.split(',')
df.explode('B')
```